# Tilestache AttributeError: Layer instance has no attribute 'palette256' error when adding Metatiles

Tags: tilestache

I have Tilestache working great over apache/mod_python. All of my mapnik.xml driven layers work well until I add a 'Metatiles' directive in the layer and then i get the following error:

AttributeError: Layer instance has no attribute 'palette256'

Here's the tilestache.cfg:

"bldglabels": {
      "provider": {
        "name": "mapnik",
        "mapfile": "/etc/mapxml/bldglabels.xml"
      },
      "metatile":
      {
        "rows": 4,
        "columns": 4,
        "buffer": 64
      }
    },

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just an update for anyone finding this: I used Tilemill to generate the mapnik xml files. adding the metatile directive to the xml still broke tilestache for me, but adding "Map {buffer-size: 256;}" to the tilemill .mss is a workaround and fixes the label cropping on tile edges. tilestache will render the xml fine with that directive int he "map" section.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of documentation about that parameter, but I was able to get my configuration working by specifying `"png options": {"palette256": True}` in my layer configuration.

Comment: I ended up not liking how that palette impacted transparency rendering, so I set it to ```False``` instead.